# Usage of apostrophe in “baker’s dozen”

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, orthography, possessives, apostrophe

In the phrase “baker’s dozen”, why does the apostrophe indicate possession of *a* (single) baker? Shouldn't it indicate possession of *all* bakers in general? Shouldn’t it be “bakers’ dozen”?

Comment: Oddly, while "baker's dozen" is always written that way, "banker's rounding" is also written "bankers' rounding". ["Farmers market"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=farmers+market%2Cfarmer%27s+market%2Cfarmers%27+market&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) is written three different ways.

Comment: To heck with English; just use Japanese. それじゃ、ベーカーのダ―ス。(Soreja, beekaa no dasu.) "Now then, baker's dozen." It could mean bakers' dozen too. Or bakers' dozens. Problem solved. :)

Comment: Related: [Happy Mother’s Day vs. Happy Mothers’ Day](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24367/apostrophes-and-caps-in-happy-mothers-day-happy-mothers-day)

Comment: If you had a married couple with the surname Baker...and they
adopted 12 children...would the kids be described as The Bakers Dozen...
with no apostrophe at all?

Comment: @Peter No; it would either be the Baker Dozen (attributive noun), or Bakers' Dozen (possessive of the parents).

Comment: "rare as a hen's teeth" or "rare as hens' teeth" are both correct.

Comment: Just write "thirteen" and be done with it!!

Answer (score 24):

Because the dozen isn't the collective property of all bakers, but of a generic baker. It's the same reason it's a *carpenter's square,* a *driver's license, a sailor's cap, a potter's wheel,* or a *greengrocer's apostrophe.*

You see both *farmer's market* and *farmers' market* because there are several farmers selling at a *farmers' market,* so you can also think of it as a market that collectively belongs to these farmers.

Comment: Both _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ (2003) and _The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language_, fifth edition (2010) give the spelling as **baker's dozen**, with no variant alternative spelling listed. According to MW, the expression has been around since 1596 (although surely not with an apostrophe in its earliest occurrences).

Answer (score 6):

It is a particular "dozen" of a particular person, an individual baker — it is the "dozen of a baker," 12+1 items. The phrase is not about a group of bakers coming together to count out a dozen, or about the total number of "dozens" of the *n* bakers in existence, which would be (12+1)*n* items.

I have heard the label *genitive of source* applied to this construction; the *'s* indicates an origin or dependency which affects the meaning of the phrase. It is actually quite common in English: we may say *it's a man's world* but never *it's a men's world*, even though the former could be interpreted as saying the world belongs to an individual man. Consider expressions like *soft as a baby's bottom* (not babies' bottoms) or *rare as hen's teeth* (not hens' teeth). We wear *soldier's caps*, collect a *day's pay*, and live a *dog's life*.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the origin of the expression you realize that the "dozen" belongs to the occupation of being a "baker" rather than to an individual baker.

So "A baker's dozen" should be understood as A + (baker's dozen) where "baker's dozen" is seen as an expression meaning thirteen rather than as (A baker)'s dozen.

Answer (score 0):

It refers to a particular baker. Since we are concerned with 12+1, the collectivity of bakers is not important so we start with the origin which is *one* baker.